# Collapsing control with binding in FluentLayout

Tags: ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

If we order two controls in fluent layout one below the other

```
this.SubviewsDoNotTranslateAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints();
this.AddConstraints(
      _lblTitle.AtTopOf(this, 10)
      , _lblTitle.AtLeftOf(this, 15)
      , _lblTitle.AtRightOf(this, 5)

      , _lblFullName.Below(_lblTitle, 5)
      , _lblFullName.AtLeftOf(this, 0)
      , _lblFullName.AtRightOf(this, 0));
```

...and we want in some scenarios to hide _lblTitle. We can do it with binding.

```
set.Bind(_lblTitle)
   .For(c => c.Hidden)
   .To(vm => vm.ShowTitle)
   .WithConversion("Visibility");
```

Problem is that _lblTitle would not collapse, that ofcourse leave us with empty space on begining.

We can try in certain situations to remove Text from label. That indeed colapse text-part of the label but does not colapse 10 points margin that we defined. What can lead to undesired effect especially if label has different background color.

I didn't try to bind Height of the control in order to hide it because I don't know on what value to set Height if I want to show hidden control which is flexible in size.

I couldn't find any solution in QuickLayout solution of the FluentLayout.

Answer (score 0):

We have something similar to this when the SizeClass changes. We Add and Remove the constraints as necessary.

In your example can you not create the Constraint for _lblFullName's Top and store that as a private variable.

```
this.fullNameTopConstraint = 
             this._lblFullName.Below(this._lblTitle).ToLayoutConstraints().First()
```

Then when the visibility of `_lblTitle` changes update the constraint to be either from the Top of `this` or from the Bottom of `_lblTitle`

Comment: Thanx for the answer. I'm aware of this solution but I find it very hard to implement. It looks very easy in this example but if you have dozen "rows" of labels and if several of them could be hidden is some cases then you have some very error-prone programming to do (changing constraints, removing constraints adding new ones..) I might end up doing just that. But it makes me very unhappy.

Comment: Most of stuff I come across during iOS development makes me unhappy :-)